# How do I use a button to draw a label in a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

I am expecting that on the click of button the label should be displayed and then the download should start. But in this below case, the frame gets stuck , say if download takes 10 min it gets stuck, and the label will be displayed only after 10.

```
def call():
 test1()
 test2()

def test1():
 button.pack_forget()
 label.pack()

def test2(): 
 "script to start download which might take 10 min"

frame=Tk()
frame.pack()
button=Button(frame,text="clickme",command=call)
label=Label(frame,text="downloading...Please wait")
button.pack()
frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first part of your code barley resamples python. There should be `def` for each function definition. Its difficult to help, if the code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

`.pack_forget()` can be a bit fiddly sometimes.
Personally I prefer to pack everything into a sort of sub-master frame, which is the only direct child of the `Tk()` window and all contents are children of the sub-master frame.

It also seems that you're forgetting to pass the variables to `call()` and subsequently to `test1`. Due to your label and button being a local variable not global you won't be able to draw or destroy them without passing them to the routine. To do this within the restraints of the Tkinter button command system you need to use the function `lambda:` (Demonstrated below).

So in the case of your code, something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

def Call(frame, mainframe, label):
    test1(frame, mainframe, label)
    test2()

def test1(frame, mainframe, label)
    mainframe.destroy()
    mainframe = Frame(frame)
    label.pack()

def test2()
    print("Only here so the program can be copied straight from SO")
    #Blegh, download stuff

frame = Tk()
mainframe = Frame(frame) #This is the sub-master frame
button = Button(mainframe, text="clickme", command=lambda:Call(frame, mainframe, label) #Using lambda here allows you to pass parameters to the definition within Tkinters buttons command restraints
label = Label(mainframe, text="downloading . . . Please wait")
button.pack()
frame.mainloop()
```

This code would function in a way where pressing the button will wipe the button from the screen and instead pack the label you wanted to pack, should you wish to keep the button for whatever reason you need only modify `test1()` by adding the line `button.pack()` and ensuring you also pass the variable as a parameter.

Comment: hi @Ethan Field, under test1 you are destroying the mainframe,and then trying to pack a label on that destroyed label?? or am i wrong??

Comment: If this question has been answered can you please close it